# Copay wallet no longer available on the Google Play store

Tags: copay

[This URL where the Copay wallet used to be](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bitpay.copay&hl=en) now just shows "We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server." Why was it removed? Was there a security issue? Is this going to affect the app installed on my phone?

Comment: Your question was very unclear and off-topic, please modify it so that ill be on-topic.

Comment: Why does the copay or play store remove the wallet? Is there any problem abour security? Thats the question.

Answer (score 2):

In early September, Google [removed Copay and a number of other Bitcoin wallet apps from the Play Store](https://bcfocus.com/news/bitpay-bitcoin-com-and-copay-wallets-removed-from-google-play-store/23007/). I don't think we know why exactly those apps were removed, but things like that do seem to happen from time to time in the crypto world. More recently (late November), [it was revealed](https://github.com/bitpay/copay/issues/9346#issuecomment-441827353) that a hacker had managed to inject code into Copay that could steal users' wallets. I don't think those two events were related, but if you have funds stored using Copay I'd definitely recommend taking steps to make sure that your version of the software does not have the vulnerability. See [here](https://github.com/bitpay/copay/issues/9346#issuecomment-441827353) and/or contact BitPay support for more information.

Answer (score -1):

But you have it installed, no? Then what's the problem?

I don't know the official line, but the github repo for it is still there 
https://github.com/bitpay/copay

Worst case scenario you can build it from source and recover the wallet (if you saved the private key). To do it on scratch you'll probably need a full node or someone who has one

Comment: Why does the copay or play store remove the wallet? Is there any problem abour security? Thats the question.

Comment: Google can just choose to remove it like they have done in many crypto ralated apps and like they label many crypto websites as malware (Bitmex as one example). Google could claim it is malware but you can simply inspect the code and see it for yourself. As far as I know, there have been no issues found with CoPay. search around, maybe even ask in Github (they might have a slack team too)